# Hibernate Validation doesn't display custom error messages in JSF 2

Tags: spring, jsf-2, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

i am using hibernate validation (4.2.0 Final) with JSF 2 and Spring
and here's my configuration:

1- **applicationContext:**

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
    <list>

    <value>classpath:messages/ValidationMessages</value>
    <value>classpath:messages/application</value>

    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

2- **faces-config.xml:**

```
<resource-bundle>
           <base-name>messages.ValidationMessages</base-name>
        </resource-bundle>
```

when trying to use the following:

```
@NotBlank(message = "{name.required}")
private String name;
```

it doesn't work, it doesn't display the message from property file, it displays **{name.required}**

please advise why it's not working.

Comment: AFAIR `hibernate-validator` always looking for `ValidationMessages` in root of classpath. I suggest to move it there.

Comment: it's already in classpath, i think that i am missing additional configuration.

Comment: I was talking about *root of classpath*, because in your example `ValidationMessages` inside `message` directory.

Comment: aha, got you, i will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was that **ValidationMessages.properties** is **not under the classpath directly**, i was putting it inside a messages folder in the classpath, when i moved it to be under classpath directly it works fine now.